# Get First Row of SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with clients and I need to show the first country of each client like a default country.

```
Table Clients
ID_Client | Name_Client
1         | Mike
2         | Jon
3         | Ben

Table Countries
ID_Country | ID_Client | Name_Country
1          | 1         | France
2          | 1         | USA
3          | 1         | England
4          | 2         | Portugal
5          | 2         | Spain
6          | 3         | Germany
```

I only want the first row of each country.

```
Example:
Mike - France
Jon - Portugal
Ben - Germany
```

I tried this but only retry 1 row:

```
SELECT Name_Client, Name_Country
FROM Clients
WHERE ID_Client =
(SELECT TOP 1 ID_Client
From Countries
order by ID_Country)

Result: 
Mike | France
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-query isn't correlated, try to use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT c.Name_Client, cn.Name_Country
FROM Clients C OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) cn.Name_Country
      From Countries CN
      WHERE cn.ID_Client = c.ID_Client
      ORDER BY cn.ID_Country
     ) cn;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Outer APPLY or CROSS APPLY as per Below example,

```
SELECT C.Name_Client + ' - ' + V.Name_Country 
FROM Clients C
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Countries CO WHERE CO.ID_Client = C.ID_Client
    ORDER BY ID_Country
) V
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ee07/7)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (ID_Client int,Name_Client varchar(255))
CREATE TABLE COUNTRIES(ID_Country int,ID_Client int,Name_Country varchar(255))
INSERT INTO CLIENTS(ID_Client,Name_Client)VALUES(1,'Mike'),(2,'Jon'),(3,'Ben')

INSERT INTO COUNTRIES(ID_Country,ID_Client,Name_Country)VALUES(1,1,'France'),
                             (2,1,'USA'),(3,1,'England'),
                             (4,2,'Portugal'),(5,2,'Spain'),
                             (6,3,'Germany')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with CTE as
(    select c.Name_Client, ct.Name_Country,
     row_number() over(partition by c.ID_Client order by ct.ID_Country) as rn 
 FROM CLIENTS c 
     left join COUNTRIES ct on c.ID_Client=ct.ID_Client
) 
select CTE.Name_Client,CTE.Name_Country from CTE where rn=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ee07/7/0)**:

```
| Name_Client | Name_Country |
|-------------|--------------|
|        Mike |       France |
|         Jon |     Portugal |
|         Ben |      Germany |
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a nested query like this try this instead.

```
SELECT clients.Name_Client, countries.Name_Country
FROM Clients clients
LEFT JOIN Countries countries on countries.ID_Client = clients.ID_Client
```

By performing the join you are matching the record and not having a subquery go off and get a bucket load of bad data.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
with cte as
(    select c.Name_Client, cn.Name_Country,
     row_number() over(partition by c.ID_Client order by ID_Country) rn clients c join country cn on c.client_id=cn.client_id
) select * form cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use common table expression and filter on the row number partitioned by the id_client. Like this the row_number is incremented until a new id_client is found.

```
WITH cte_countries AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Client ORDER BY ID_Client) AS Row#,
Countries.*
FROM Countries)
SELECT * FROM Clients cli
JOIN cte_countries coun ON cli.ID_Client = coun.ID_Client
WHERE coun.Row# = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Name_Client, Name_Country ,
RwNumbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by c.ID_Client order by cl.ID_Country)
from CLIENTS c
JOIN COUNTRIES cl
ON cl.ID_Client = c.ID_Client
) as f 
WHERE f.RwNumbr = 1
```